# MongoDB is not connecting from node.js using docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am not able to conect to `mongodb` from my `node.js` application. I am using docker for both `mongodb and node` and when I am running the container I am getting the following error.

**Error:**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

I am explaining my `dockerfile` below.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.22.1-alpine3.9
COPY ./app /app


WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/node-js
RUN echo "$WORKDIR"
RUN pwd
RUN ls -lt
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8081


WORKDIR /app

#Install mongodb
RUN cp /etc/apk/repositories /etc/apk/repositories_bak
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' > /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update &&  apk --no-cache --update add mongodb
RUN mongo --version
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
EXPOSE 27017
```

This is my `Dockerfile` where I have mentioned all the code for `node.js and install the mongoDB`. I can build the container successfully and also I can access the mongo inside the container. I am explaining my node.js code below to get the connection.

```
const dbUser = 'admin';
  const dbPass = 'admin';
  const dbServer = '127.0.0.1';
  const dbPort = '27017';
  let dbName = 'admin';
  const dbUrl = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPass}@${dbServer}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`;
  console.log('url', dbUrl);
  const dbOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  };

  MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, dbOptions).then(function (client) {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
    dbName = process.env.MONGO_DATABASE || 'demo-db';
    let connObj = client.db(dbName);

    connObj.addUser(dbUser, dbPass, {
      roles: [{
        role: 'readWrite',
        db: dbName
      }]
    }).then(result => {
      client.close(true);
      console.log(`${dbName} database and user are created!`);
    }).catch(err => {
      client.close(true);
      console.log(`Error occurred while creating ${dbName} database and assigning user => ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    });
  });
```

Here I am trying to connect to mongodb after running container but its throwing the above error. Please help me to resolve this error and get the connection for mongodb successfully.

Comment: A Docker container usually only runs one process; you'd typically run MongoDB in a separate container (maybe even using the prebuilt `mongo` Docker Hub image).  Are you getting a "connection refused" type error, because the container is only running the Node application?  What's your image's `CMD`?

Comment: yes I am getting connection refused error. In this container I can install mongo db and also access db using cli. But from node.js its not working.